# MySQL #1054 error code for UPDATE query

Tags: python, mysql

I currently have a MySQL table that looks like:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM settings;
+--------------+-------+
| name         | value |
+--------------+-------+
| connected    | 0     |
+--------------+-------+
```

and I'm trying to update the value with a timestamp for connected through Python with this code:

```
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="password", db="database")
cursor1 = db1.cursor()
cursor1.execute("UPDATE settings SET value = 'ts' WHERE name = connected")
db1.commit()
cursor1.close()
```

This returns to me:

> cursor1.execute("""UPDATE settings SET value = 'ts' WHERE name = connected""")
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
>   self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>   raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'connected' in 'where clause'")

and I just can't figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your query is trying to compare the `name` column to a column called `connected`. If you want to compare the `name` column to the literal string "connected", then you mean `WHERE name='connected'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1054, "Unknown column 'connected' in 'where clause'

This error clearly states that `connected` is consider as a column name.

But here `connected` is string value that want to match with the columnname `name`.

So you need to place a single quote around the `connected` string to solve the issue:

```
cursor1.execute("UPDATE settings SET value = 'ts' WHERE name = 'connected'")
```